# Accessing dll from applet

Tags: dll, applet

I have a "proof of concept" piece of work that crosses over into some unfamiliar territory. I have some experience on J2EE technologies. I'm tasked with connecting an EFTPOS machine to an web application. I am planning to use applet to interact with dll. dll will be running on the client side.

I need to interact with one dll from web application. Please provide me any guidance on this, as I am new to it. I tried interacting with dll from standalone java program, but not able to connect from web application. Any sample codes will be very helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is perfectly possible with an applet. I "connected" an electronice signing device before and it was working very well. Depening on what kind of .dll we are talking about here you need to do the following things:

1.) Create a java access layer / interface for your dll, so that you are able to call the dll functions from java. Depending what kind of dll we are talking about there are several possibilities. The base technology is [JNI](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/) which is however quite cumbersome to use but luckily there are much more convienient ways out there:

- use [JNA](https://github.com/twall/jna) (if it is a **C** dll)
- use [Jacob](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jacob-project/) (if it is a **COM** component)
- use [bridj](https://code.google.com/p/bridj/) (if it is a **c++** dll. You may try [swig](http://www.swig.org/index.php) but haven't used that, so can't tell)

2.) Put your dll inside a jar file and distribute it alongside your applet. How this works is quite nicely described in the jacob project which provides an example for that. You can find it in the source package under `jacob-1.17_src.zip\jacob-1.17\samples\com\jacob\samples\applet` The example describes the JNLP way to access a native library which will work above java version 1.6.0_10. If you have to use a lower version for some reason, it is also possible but is slightly more tricky...

3.) One more side note: Since the latest available java version (1.7.0_51 or 1.6.0_71) due to security, some rules have been added or tightened for java applets. Now you have to sign your applet with an official certificate and set the right attributes/properties in the manifest, jnlp files. But this has been discussed in great detail here so just search for it. I would probably use a slightly older version for development and if that is working, figuring out how to make it work in the latest java version...

4.) Regarding the interaction part there are also several possibilities. Your Java Applet can call jscript methods from the website it is running in (or also the other way around) or the applet directly communicates with your server. You have all possibilities on that front...

Comment: Thanks a lot, it will help me a lot to learn and work on my project. One more point, if I use Javascript or Action class instead of Applets, will there be any issues

Comment: It is not possible to call a dll from jscript. What do you mean by "action class"? 
If you are happy with the answer your are welcome to accept it - this helps other users. (Click on the check mark below the number left to the post)

Comment: I want to call dll functions from a Servlet. The dll is dotnet based. please provide any sample code how to access dll to alishacooper2010@gmail.com